# How to resolve the issue uncaught TypeError :cannot read property top of null?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this code to create a floating sidebar that sticks at right of the browser window.

I am getting this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null

The Error is shown from this function. Do you have any solution to resolve this?

```
function setCaptionPosition(){
  if(showBgCaption)
  {
    var posTop = $('#bgImages   .active').position().top+$('#bgImages').position().top-10;
    var maxTop = $('#content').height()-$('#bgText').height()-20;
    posTop = (posTop>maxTop)?maxTop:posTop;
    posTop = (posTop<-20)?-20:posTop;
    $('#bgText').stop().animate({top:posTop, opacity:'1'}, 500, 'easeOutQuad');
   }
  else
  {
    $('#bgText').stop().animate({opacity:'0'}, 500, 'easeOutQuad');
  }
}
```

Comment: Type $('#bgImages   .active') on the console. What do see ?

Comment: If the answer to the above is null, the problem lies in your selector $('#bgImages   .active'), so for that you should show us your html.

Comment: Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'top' of null shows on the line " var posTop = $('#bgImages .active').position().top+$('#bgImages').position().top-10;"

Comment: top of null means $('#bgImages .active') returns null which means that the element that you intend to select via this $('#bgImages .active') is not present. Hence it would be good to show your html as well.